# Database issue for everyone (QUERY)

Tags: database, tablename

I want to create a query that generates the table name.
I tried something like this :

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA='mytableName'
```

but it return an empty query. So , any ideas ? Thx

Comment: `WHERE AND` isn't going to run, surely?

Comment: it return the same empty query without and, srry my mistake

Comment: I updated my answer. You should try TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo', it looks like your schema 'mytableName' is really empty.

Comment: SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME='mytableName'     => This solves the problem, thx u guys

Comment: Am I missing something or would this just return 'myTableName' every time? What's the point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why `WHERE AND TABLE_SCHEMA='mytableName'` 
The `AND` is invalid at this point.

Besides the Tablename is in the column TABLE_NAME not TABLE_SCHEMA, maby you should try to filter using the schema name instead of the table name like:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='YOUR_SCHEMA_NAME'
```

Or if you need information regarding a specific table:

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME='YOUR_TABLE_NAME'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is incorrect syntax at "WHERE AND".

You should execute:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='mytableName'
```

You should try TABLE_SCHEMA='dbo', it looks like your schema 'mytableName' is really empty.

Comment: it return the same empty query without and, srry my mistake

Answer (score 0):

To start with: that query is invalid (remove the `AND`).

2nd it's empty because there are no tables within the schema (also called database) named `mytableName`.

Also take a look at `SHOW TABLES` ([documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-tables.html)) and `SHOW DATABASES` ([documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-databases.html))